# Javascript Separate Percent from number

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to separate two numbers from each other

this is the value of string "**TLP 62.48 TPL 5,632.730.00%**"

when I use the code segment

```
string.split(/(?=.{5}$)/).join(' ')
```

my string is equal to "**TLP 62.48 TPL 5,632.73 0.00%**"

The problem is if the percent is larger than it is now.

If the sting is "**TLP 62.48 TPL 622.8328.00%**"
The out out is incorrect. Im trying to separate the percent from the amount.
the amount is in money and only goes to two decimal places. so the output should be
"**TLP 62.48 TPL 622.83 28.00%**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the amount is in money and only goes to two decimal places

Match the decimal place instead.

Instead of splitting and joining, you could use `.replace` instead, to add a space:

```js
const str = 'TLP 62.48 TPL 622.8328.00%';
const separated = str.replace(/\.\d{2}(?=\d+\.\d+%$)/, '$& ');
console.log(separated);
```

`\.\d{2}(?=\d+\.\d+%$)` matches:

- `\.` - a literal `.`
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?=\d+\.\d+%$)` - lookahead for

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `\.` - a literal `.`
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `%` - a `%`
  - `$` - the end of the string

So it'll match the decimal portion of the money amount and replace it with that portion (`$&`) plus a space.